# you did not pass the checksum security check in bbb

Tags: checksum, bigbluebutton

Referred API documentation of bigbluebutton for create call. My API URL is like this: https://server_name/bigbluebutton/api/create?name=Sample&meetingID=B3XdYtdzdoV1&attendeePW=1234&moderatorPW=2345&checksum=d7b20f96f3616a69ae4a50eb1c0472428283c63a
Still it is showing the checksum error. I really have no idea why I am facing this error because according to me everything is correct

```
    $defaults = array(
        'name' => '',
        'meetingID'=>'',//MeetingId
        'attendeePW'=>'',//pass the attendee(student) password
        'moderatorPW'=>'',//pass the moderator (instructor) password
        'welcome'=>'',
        'maxParticipants'=>'',
        'record'=>false,
        'duration'=>'', //(minutes)
        'meta'=>'',//metavalue
        'allowStartStopRecording'=>false,
        'webcamsOnlyForModerator'=>'',//boolean
        'logo'=>'',//url
        'bannerText'=>'',
        'bannerColor'=>'',
        'copyright'=>'',
        'meta_endCallbackUrl'=>site_url(), //redirect to this site
        'meta_bn-recording-ready-url'=>'',
    );

    $args = array_merge($defaults, $args);
    $salt = $this->get_salt();
```

$url = $this->get_server().'api/create?'.http_build_query($args);
 $checksum = sha1('create'.http_build_query($args).$salt);

$bbb_url = $url.'&checksum='.$checksum;
 $response = wp_remote_get($bbb_url);

when tried print_r($bbb_url); It is showing above url with the error message
refer: 
[a link](http://prntscr.com/ow89cp)!

Comment: when you are creating checksum you need to append your moderator password with the secrete key and then put the query stringin sha1, now it will generate you a checksum

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the answer by myself. After a lot of hit and trials, it was still showing this error. So I break my parameters and then individually test the values of each parameter.
The problem was with my server secret which was not correct.
Finally, it is resolved

Answer (score 1):

on your server past this command

```
bbb-conf --secret
```

then it will return u sth like this:

```
URL: http://bbb.example.com/bigbluebutton/
Secret: ECCJZNJWLPEA3YB6Y2LTQGQD3GJZ3F93

Link to the API-Mate:
https://mconf.github.io/api-mate/#server=https://bbb.urserver.com/bigbluebutton/&sharedSecret=ECCJZNJWLPEA3YB6Y2LTQGQD3GJZ3F93
```

use the git hub link to navigate to a page full of suitable API documents

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve by breaking the parameters and testing the value of each parameter individually. The problem was with my server secret

Answer (score 0):

you must try this documentation to create api

https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html

Hope this will help out you

Answer (score 0):

There should be NO space between API_SECRET= and the actual secret

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already found - " I break my parameters and then individually test the values of each parameter. The problem was with my server secret which was not correct"